# Add button Dropzone

Tags: reactjs, dropzone.js

I have two components List and Form. On these components, I'm using Dropzone.
I disabled click, just Drag and Drop is possible.
But, on the form component, I would like to add a button, which enables the user to add a document in browsing.

In the form component, I call my component dropzone

```
<UploadZone onupload={this.props.onCreateDocument} onsuccessupload={this.uploadedfile} lastfileupload={this.props.lastuploadfile} />
```

I've added my button:

```
<RaisedButton label="Add" primary={true} onClick={this.browseDz}/>

browseDz = () => {
   
}
```

I don't know how call Dropzone on the button to add a document.
Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't use Dropzone for this part, you implement it yourself. You could use the trick where you put this button in a `<label htmlFor={id}>` and have a file input with the same id. You'll have two ways of receiving files, so just store the latest selection from the user in one state key.